# Focus a specific element given its key

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, textinput

I'm developing a small app to guess a word. Instead of a single `TextInput` I want to give clues about how many characters the word have and maybe even start with some characters already revealed.

To do that I'm creating one `TextInput` for each character, then I'm setting the first TextInput with `autofocus=true`.

What I need is that when the user inputs a character in the current `TextInput` the focus jumps to the next one.

To create the Inputs, I am assigning a consecutive integer to each key, and passing this key to the function `handleKeyPress`. What I need inside this function is something that focuses the `TextInput` with key equal to i+1.

My code:

```
handleKeyPress(i, input_text) {
    // Here I need to focus the TextInput with key===(i+1)
    const text = this.state.text;
    text[i] = input_text;
    this.setState({
      text: text,
    });
}

render() {
    let ToRender = [];
    let n= 5;  // number of characters

    // First Input has autofocus set to true
    ToRender.push(
      <TextInput
        key={0}
        size="1"
        autofocus={true}
        value={this.state.text[0]}
        onChangeText={(text) => this.handleKeyPress(0, text)}
      />
    );

    // generate the rest of the Inputs
    for (let i=1; i<n; i++) {
      ToRender.push(
        <TextInput
          key={i}
          size="1"
          value={this.state.text[i]}
          onChangeText={(text) => this.handleKeyPress(i, text)}
        />
      );
    }

    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {ToRender.map((e) => e)}
      </View>
    );
}
```

How can I focus a specific element given it's key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I managed to solve it.

First, I have to reference the elements by the field `ref` instead of `key`, and access them using `this.refs[i].focus()` to focus the ith element:

```
<TextInput
    key={i}
    ref={i}
    size="1"
    autofocus={true}
    value={this.state.text[i]}
    onChangeText={(text) => this.handleKeyPress(i, text)}
/>
```

Then inside the function `handleKeyPress` I can do:

```
handleKeyPress(i, input_text) {
    this.refs[i+1].focus();
}
```